# Alter a custom block depending on custom block type

Tags: theming, 8, blocks

I need to alter all the blocks of custom type 'my_custom_block_type' that get displayed on my site.
In order to achieve this, i added a custom prerender in which  i filter on the block bundle :

```
function my_module_block_view_alter(array &$build, \Drupal\Core\Block\BlockPluginInterface $block) {
  $build['#pre_render'][] = '_custom_block_custom_prerender';
}

function _custom_block_custom_prerender(array $build) {
  if ($build['content']['#block_content']) {
    $block_bundle = $build['content']['#block_content']->bundle();

    if ($build['content']['#block_content']->bundle() === 'my_custom_block_type') {
      // do your thing here
    }
  }
  return $build;
}
```

I think it's not the most elegant way to do this.

I tried to enhance this, but i did not manage, after several attempts, to retrieve the block type directly inside a hook_block_view_alter or a hook_block_build_alter ...

```
function hook_block_view_alter(array &$build, \Drupal\Core\Block\BlockPluginInterface $block) {
  // things
}
function hook_block_build_alter(array &$build, \Drupal\Core\Block\BlockPluginInterface $block) {
  // stuff
}
```

Is there a way to easily get the custom block type inside those two hooks ?

Comment: Try hook_block_content_view()/view_alter(), that gives you the block_content entity as an argument, just like hook_node_view(). Depends on what you need to do

Comment: thanks @Berdir, hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view did the trick and is more straightforward.

Comment: Hey, could you move the solution into a desired answer and mark that as accepted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view/8.2.x)/[`hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view_alter/8.2.x), that gives you the `block_content` `$entity` as an argument, just like [`hook_node_view()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7.x).

Comment: @leymannx Thanks for improving, but as I commented, you should then actually use $entity and you can also type hint it on BlockContentInterface to get more specific method autocomplete.

Comment: I see! Removed OP's code.