# hook to alter custom blocks?

Tags: 8, blocks

I am having a problem with my custom blocks rendering, and I want to programmatically manipulate the blocks to troubleshoot the issue.

I used [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/229269/alter-a-custom-block-depending-on-custom-block-type) to add this hook to my module:

```
function mymodule_block_view_alter(array &$build, Drupal\Core\Block\BlockPluginInterface $block) {
  drupal_set_message($block->getBaseId());
}
```

However, when I navigate to my site, I see only the base ids of system blocks:

```
- page_title_block
- system_main_block
- help_block
- local_tasks_block
```

My site's header and footer are made of custom blocks, so I should be seeing their ids.

How can I programmatically access my custom blocks?

**Edit** this is my actual code:

```
$ cat my_block_hooks.module
<?php

function my_block_hooks_block_view_alter(array &$build, Drupal\Core\Block\BlockPluginInterface $block) {
  drupal_set_message(__FUNCTION__ . "() id: " . $block->getBaseId() );
}
```

And here's a screenshot:

[image]

You can see that all the system blocks show up, but my custom block does not.

This is the custom block as I have it set up:

[image]

And here I have it placed in the layout:

[image]

And of course, I've cleared the cache many times to get to this point.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any news on this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The type of entity you are dealing with defines the hook you need to implement; in this case it is NOT `block` but rather `block_content`, as provided by the "[Custom Block](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/custom_block/overview)" core module.

**N.B.**: It is generally good practice to use more specific hooks when possible, as it will have a general effect on your code's performance, i.e. your hook implementation will be called less times if it is more specific. In your case, instead of going through all blocks available on any page during page loading, you are going through only custom blocks (`block_content` entities).

In order to get your [`hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view/8.6.x)/[`hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view_alter/8.6.x) implementation to work, you need to replace `ENTITY_TYPE` with `block_content`. That should give you the following code (which I tested and works):

```
use Drupal\block_content\Entity\BlockContent;
...
function my_block_hooks_block_content_view_alter(array &$build, BlockContent $custom_block) {
  drupal_set_message(__FUNCTION__ . "() id: " . $custom_block->id() );
}
```

And the visual result:

[image]

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

You're using the built-in custom block which ships with Drupal. 
In your code your getting the baseId which is in your case `block_content` and it is shown in your screenshot actually.
I think you need to use `$block->id()` instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [getPluginId](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21block%21src%21Entity%21Block.php/function/Block%3A%3AgetPluginId/8.2.x) to get the id of the block:

```
function my_block_hooks_block_view_alter(array &$build, Drupal\Core\Block\BlockPluginInterface $block) {
  drupal_set_message(__FUNCTION__ . "() id: " . $block->getPluginId());
}
```

here is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should be seeing the IDs of your custom blocks. Here are some things you can try:

- Make sure you actually have the custom block nicely defined and placed on your *Manage blocks* page.
- Make sure your custom block is actually visible on the page? Return some temporary output like "foo" from your custom block plugin and make sure that the "foo" is visible on the page.
- Try removing cache for your block temporarily by adding `$build['#cache']['max-age'] = 0;` to your block's output.
- Drush `drush cr` or clear cache and see if your custom block is visible.
- Check the visibility rules for your custom block in block configuration. Try removing all visibility rules temporarily and see if the block shows up.
- If you've implemented any block access rules, try disabling them to see if your block becomes visible.
- Multiple blocks can have the same `Base ID`. Try doing `$block->getPluginId()` or `$block->id()`. In your case, it should give you an item like `block_content:UUID` where `UUID` is the unique ID of the custom block you created in your custom block library.

The ID of your block not showing up is basically sounds like your block is not being displayed on the page.

Comment: I've updated my question to address some of the questions you've raised. It's on a new Drupal 8.6.3 clean install, do I don't have any custom visiblity rules (other than what would have come out of the box). Hopefully you can help spot my mistake : )

Comment: Also check that it is  placed in the currently active (default) theme. Sometimes when you have multiple active ones, it might be placed in block set of a non-default one.

Comment: The item `block_content` corresponds to your custom block. Since you're dealing with custom content blocks, the base ID for all blocks created in the custom block library will be `block_content`. So use `$block->getPluginId()` to get the unique block ID. It will be something like `block_content:UUID`.

Comment: Also, it seems like you're new to Drupal. It will be great if you could say the exact problem you're facing while rendering the blocks. Maybe there is an easier solution?

Answer (score 0):

```php
use Drupal\block_content\Entity\BlockContent;

//...

function my_block_hooks_block_content_view_alter(array &$build, BlockContent $custom_block) {
  drupal_set_message(__FUNCTION__ . "() id: " . $custom_block->id() );
}
```

You will get your block id here, based on that set condition and override that specific block output.

```php
use Drupal\block_content\Entity\BlockContent;

// ...

function my_block_hooks_block_content_view_alter(array &$build, BlockContent $custom_block) {
    if($custom_block->id() == 5){
       $build['content']['#markup'] = Markup::create('Your text');
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I am going to take a wild guess, but have you tried clearing the cache? Custom blocks normally do not contain dynamic data and as such can be heavily cached. This causes the block output to be rendered without your hook getting called.

In the configuration menu go to development > performance and hit the 'Clear all caches' button. Then go back to the page with your blocks and see if it made a change. Alternatively you can install the [devel module](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) to clear the cache from each page directly.